# How to Import Nuget Module to powershell script

Tags: powershell, nuget, nuget-package

I would like to access some of the NuGet commands from my powershell script(mybuild.ps1). I am not sure how to import the NuGet Module so that I can access commands like get-Project, get-Package etc.

Thanks any help is much appreciated. I am new to VS development.